# How to cancel asyncio tasks by name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have N number of asyncio tasks running like this.

```
import asyncio

def main(tasks):
   for task in tasks:
      await 

asyncio.create_task(do_something(task),name=task['name'])
asyncio.run(main(tasks))
```

After sometime, I need to cancel only the particular task using task name.

Answer (score 2):

You could find the task by name using `asyncio.all_tasks()`:

```
task, = [task for task in asyncio.all_tasks() if task.get_name() == name]
task.cancel()
```

Note that `get_name()` requires Python 3.8. For earlier Python versions you can maintain your own name-to-task dictionary when you create the tasks.