# When should an asyncio Task be given a name?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Since Python 3.8 a `Task` (in asyncio) can have its name.

```
asyncio.create_task(coroutine(), name='some text')   # name is optional
```

The documentation says:

- if no name ... the Task implementation generates a default name
- the name will be visible in the repr() output of a task object

If an existing package intended for developers does not need this feature, would it help these developers to make an update and give explicit names to tasks the package creates? If yes, what is considered a helpful task name?

Comment: It can be useful for [canceling tasks by name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64764679/2745495)